# How to benchmark resources consumed by a Django application?

Tags: django, command-line, server, backend, benchmarking

How to monitor resource consumption of a Django application for the backend server only, that is the resource consumption for each request and response cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Django Debug Toolbar - https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It can help you to determine resourced used for request and response cycle i.e CPU. You can also set it up to monitor SQL and cache time.

Here is an example of live website:

[image: Django Debug Toolbar]